# Are trivial zeros of the zeta function important?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, zeroes

Non-trivial zeros play an important (main) role in the distribution of prime numbers.
Are there theorems in which trivial zeros play an important (main) role?

Comment: Sure. Look at the explicit formula that expresses Chebyshev's $\psi(x)$ (well, the modified version $\psi_0(x)$) in terms of a sum over the nontrivial zeros, e.g., at the start of the question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/262868/about-the-explicit-formula-of-chebyshev-psi-function.  The proof of the formula also involves accounting for the trivial zeros, which is where the last term $\log(1 - 1/x^2)$ comes from.

Comment: Basically, it is necessary to take them into account for things to work. They are understood well-enough that they make nearly no difference overall.

Comment: For _exact_ formulas (such as Explicit Formulas) they must be included, but the size of their contribution is much less than the critical-strip zeros (since they are far to the left).

Comment: Also, in symmetrizing the meromorphic Riemann zeta function to the entire Landau-Riemann xi function, the trivial zeros take out the poles of a multiplying factorial which removes the pole of the zeta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you tagged this 'reference request', I'm going to answer with a theorem in my own paper *"Euler, the symmetric group, and the Riemann zeta function."*

Let $\pi$ be a permutation in the symmetric group $S_n$.  An *ascent* is an occurrence of $\pi(j)<\pi(j+1)$ for $1\le j\le n-1$.  For
example, the permutation $(24513)$ has $3$ ascents.  The *Eulerian number* $\genfrac{\langle}{\rangle}{0pt}{1}{n}{k}$ is defined to be
the number of permutations in $S_n$ with exactly $k$ ascents.  (The Eulerian numbers are not to be confused with the
Euler numbers $E_n$.)   There is a surprising identity for alternating sums of Eulerian numbers: For integer $n\ge 1$ we have
$$
\zeta(-n)=\frac{ \sum_{k=1}^n  (-1)^{k} \genfrac{\langle}{\rangle}{0pt}{0}{n}{k}}{2^{n+1}(1-2^{n+1})}.
$$

Of course, $\zeta(-n)$ can be expressed in closed form in terms of the Bernoulli numbers by 
$$
\zeta(-n)=-\frac{B_{n+1}}{n+1},
$$
so the theorem is also an identity relating Eulerian numbers to Bernoulli numbers.  However, the proof is direct.  It's also not not deep; it consists of identities in Concrete Mathematics by Graham, Knuth and Patashnik, along with Abel summation.

Comment: The  last equation follows directly from Riemann's Mellin transform for the Riemann zeta. The first can be generalized (https://oeis.org/A131758) to $$E(s,-1)/[ 2^ss! ] = -2Li(-s,-1)/s! = (2-2^{s+2})  \zeta(-s)/s!,$$ where $s$ is any real, $E(n,t)$ are the Eulerian polynomials (https://oeis.org/A173018) and $Li$ are the polylogarithms. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Comment: @TomCopeland As I said in my answer, it's not as deep as that; it's Abel summation and combinatorics.  I realize of course it can be derived from Riemann's work.

Comment: Breadth is the primary emphasis ( I was fairly confident that you know how to derive the formulas any number of ways, as I am)  for users looking for connections, not answers to test questions or Olympiad coaching--connections among the Eulerian (and, therefore, Gennochi, Euler, ordered Bell, Laguerre polynomials, positroids/Grassmannians, polytopes such as the permutohedra and stellahedra, and other constructs in combinatorics and geometry as well as analysis ) and  Bernoulli  polynomials and interpolations to the full Riemann zeta function, not only the trivial zeros.

Answer (score 5):

A conjecture of Quillen-Lichtenbaum

$$
\lim_{s \to n} (n-s)^{-\mu_n} \zeta_F (-s) = \pm \frac{\mid{K_{2n} (O_F)_{tor} }\mid}{\mid{K_{2n+1} (O_F)_{tor}}\mid} R_{F,n} * 2^{?}\\
$$

where $F$ is the number field like $\mathbb{Q}$ and $O_F$ is the integers therein generalizing $\mathbb{Z}$ in the case of Riemann zeta. $\mu_n$ is the multiplicity of the zero there. That makes sure you don't just get $0$. $K_\bullet (O_F)_{tor} $ means the torsion subgroup of algebraic K theory of that ring. $R_{F,n}$ is a so-called regulator and $2^?$ is for an unknown power of $2$. So you see the left hand side is leading information about when you have zeroes at negative integers.

This is proven in a bunch of cases via Voevodsky. In the $O_F=\mathbb{Z}$ case you just get the numerators and denominators of the Bernoulli numbers. That recovers the $-\frac{B_{n+1}}{n+1}$ above up to signs, powers of 2 and regulators.

So if you are interested in computing anything in the RHS, zooming in on the zeroes of the associated $\zeta_F$ are the most important.