# Dirichlet eta function and Stirling Permutations

Tags: co.combinatorics, riemann-zeta-function, permutations, dirichlet-series, oeis

The [Stirling permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_permutation) of order $k$ is a permutation of the multiset $1, 1, 2, 2, ..., k, k$. The [Dirichlet $\eta$-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) is a function closely related to the [Riemann $\zeta$-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).

According to [OEIS A156919](https://oeis.org/A156919), the Stirling permutations *were discovered while studying certain properties of the Dirichlet eta function.*

Unfortunatly, that statement is not explained any further, and a literature search lead to zero connections between these two objects.

> What is the connection between the Stirling permutations and the Dirichlet $\eta$-function?

Any hint or reference to the literature would be much apprechiated.

Comment: See the answer to this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277030/are-trivial-zeros-of-the-zeta-function-important/277038#277038. The reference to Abel summation is because one is really using the $\eta$ not $\zeta$ function.  More on this is in the book cited there: Concrete Mathematics by Graham and Knuth

Comment: @Stopple Thanks for the comment. I see that there is a connection to the Permutations of symmetric group, but I wonder what the connection to the Stirling permutations is. I am not able to extract that from the referenced link, could you please explain a bit more detailed? In particular, is there a connection between the Abel summation and the Stirling permutations? Thank you!

Comment: The comment in the OEIS entry was added Jul 2016 by Neil Sloane. You coul email him to ask for an explanation.

Comment: @Somos: I asked him, he suggested me to ask the person who made the specific comment, which i did but didnt receive an answer.

Comment: For what it's worth, MathSciNet showed 9 matches for "Stirling permutation", and none of the reviews contained any reference to Dirichlet (nor to Riemann).

Comment: @NicoDean I don't know a connection to Stirling permutations; that's why it's a comment and not an answer - but maybe a starting point?